# How to add a UIActivityIndicator from an NSObject class and control it .?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Class A: UIViewController
Class B: NBOject class.

Add a UIActivityIndicator in Class A from Class B. control it from Class B.

Comment: "Control it" - Does that mean to responsive UI control from Class B?. If it is YES than there is no need to do this because at that time you can see UI of Class B. So that use delegates to change dynamic control for UIActivityIndicator.

Comment: 'control it' would mean , start and stop animation

Answer (score 0):

I will do like this.

In appdelegate,

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ClassA *classA;
+ (AppDelegate *)instance;
```

.m

```
+ (AppDelegate *)instance
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

In Class A,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [AppDelegate instance].classA = self; 
}
```

Then, in class B, which is NSObject class, you can just call class A via AppDelegate like this.

.h

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
```

.m

```
- (void)addActivityIndicator
{
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    [[AppDelegate instance].classA addsubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: how do you stop animation ?

Comment: You can use this.    [self.activityIndicatorView  stopAnimating];